# Iterator (with struts2) is not working

Tags: struts2, iterator

I am trying to show a List. But nothing is displayed.
I used this tutorial:
http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts2/struts2controltags/iterator-tag.shtml

but actually it is not working

Does anybody sees an error in this tutorial?

edit:

Thats **ShowKeywords.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Iterator Tag Example!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1><span style="background-color: #FFFFcc">Iterator Tag Example!</span></h1>
  <s:iterator value="myList" status="myListStatus">
  <s:property /><br>
  </s:iterator>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

        <!-- mapping of global-results and global-exceptions -->

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false"/>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false"/>

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
    <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
    </result-types> 

    <default-action-ref name="Start"/>


<action name="ShowTest" class="de.nordakademie.librarymgmt.action.ShowTest">
  <result>showKeywords</result>
    </action> 
    </package>

    </package>
</struts>
```

**tiles**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
        "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="main" template="/jsp/main.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Dashboard"/>
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/jsp/menu.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/jsp/header.jsp"/>
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/jsp/start.jsp"/>
    </definition>


    <definition name="showKeywords" extends="main">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Stichworte anzeigen"/>
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/jsp/ShowKeywords.jsp"/>
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

**action ShowTest**

```
package de.nordakademie.librarymgmt.action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

import java.util.*;

public class ShowTest extends ActionSupport{

  /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private List<String> myList;

  public String execute()throws Exception{
  myList = new ArrayList<String>();
  myList.add("Fruits");
  myList.add("Apple");
  myList.add("Mango");
  myList.add("Orange");
  myList.add("Pine Apple");
  return SUCCESS;
  }

  public List<String> getMyList(){
  return myList;
  }
```

}

Comment: Looks fine apart from the lowercase class names. You will have to show us some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `</package>` is closed **twice** in struts.xml (a well-indented code would have immediately shown that);
- you are returning a standard result, not a Tiles result; put `default="true"` in your result definition:

  ```
  <result-type name="tiles" 
               default="true"
               class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
  ```
- 2.0 **DTD** is **old**, update it with the correct DTD.

Ensure you have all the libraries needed and that they're the right versions.

Comment: i updated it, but it was actually a different mistake :( Action wasnt starting...